# Web authentication not working correctly for Azure B2C

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-ad-b2c

I've created a new web project and selected the authentication via Azure AD B2C using my working tenant.

When I run the code and try to log in, the only User which is recognised is the account I used to create the tenant; no other B2C users in that tenant are recognised.

Why is this, and how do I fix it, please

Comment: Using Azure AD accoutns to sign in B2C?  Did you refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

Comment: Wayne, No, I'm trying to sign-in to B2C using a B2C user. This usually works OK when logging into a website which requires B2C authentication, but doesn't seem to work when authenticating from a new asp.net web app.

Comment: I've found another issue; if I log out, I get the "logged out - close your browser" message, but if I open my page again, it behaves as if I'm still logged in - the login page isn't displayed, and my page does.

Comment: Another issue: When logging out, it doesn't call the supplied and registered callback URL. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else suffering from this issue, the blog post:

https://saraford.net/2017/11/09/securing-and-calling-a-web-api-using-azure-ad-b2c/
 that it
seems to cover it...

About 1/3 of the way down she states that it: "**doesn’t work with B2C**"

If only Microsoft had told us that...